# Chrome/Firefox unique proxy per tab?

Tags: c#, firefox, google-chrome, proxy, automation

I am wondering if there exists a plugin or possible library that allows you to control Firefox or Chrome and set proxies on a per-tab basis.

I am trying to make it such that each tab in the browser has a unique proxy so connections from one tab do not appear to come from the same IP as another tab.  I am probably going to have to take into account cookies being isolated as well since it would be connecting to a single domain, but that's something to focus on a bit later.

I cannot use HttpWebRequest since the site uses quite a bit of Javascript for data manipulation before sending it back to the server.